# Is nervousness a kind of illness?

Tags: medications, mental-health, treatment

Is nervousness a kind of illness? For example, we are nervous when we meet a lot of  people or we are afraid to talk or perform in front of a large audience during a meeting. What is the best way to omit it?

Comment: No, nervousness is actually more of a psychological response when doing something we are not familiar with arising from anticipation of a negative experience from that action as a precaution. It could be anything from fear of rejection in social interaction to more warranted fear of physical trauma when doing a dangerous physical activity like sky diving or base jumping

Comment: If it's chronic, then it may be better to refer to 'nervousness' as 'Anxiety' -- for accuracy and reduction of brevity.